# ROR 3.1: Bundle update fails (eventmachine gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Please, help me to tackle with bundle and gem dependencies.

RoR on Windows 7.
i'm trying to run bundle update, but while update process I get:

> Italling eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions Unfortunately,
>   a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler
>   issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we
>   can fix it. Thanks!
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in
>   `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem
>   native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
>   ..

Bundle update stops at this point.

Eventmachine is needed for thin web server.
i've installed event machine manually: gem install eventmachine --pre

in my gemfile i've got:

```
gem 'thin' (nothing about eventmachine)
```

after bundle install/update in my gemfile.lock:

```
...
eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.4.1-x86-mingw32)
...
thin (1.2.11-x86-mingw32)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
..
DEPENDENCIES
      eventmachine
      rails (= 3.1)
      ....
      thin
```

if I run "bundle install" its ok

if I run server (thin start) - it starts ok.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved it. needed to lock the version in gemfile, to tell bundle that I need version that I :

gem 'eventmachine', "1.0.0.beta.4.1

**EDIT:** (11/14/2012) The gem version is not beta anymore. you won't be having problem with installing the gem anymore. :)

Comment: As you said, it's out of beta.That means you can lock it to 1.0.0 stable:

`gem 'eventmachine', "1.0.0"`