# "Bundle install" fails with "thin", and cannot point a different "eventmachine"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, thin

I work with Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows.

**I have a trouble to do "bundle install" due to a "thin" gem, for my app.

My original GEMFILE looks like this:

```
gem "sinatra"
gem "mogli"
gem "json"
gem "httparty"
gem "thin"
```

Running "bundle install" causes `Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions` which fails. Error is described here: [Cannot install thin on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649252/cannot-install-thin-on-windows)
Just to mention that "gem install thin" is successful!

Some people on the net, facing this issue, suggested to install 
"eventmachine" version 1.0.0.beta.4.1 which I did: 
`gem list --local` shows `eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.4.1 x86-mingw32, 1.0.0.beta.2 x86-mingw32)`

Yet "bundle install" fails.

In another post: [ROR 3.1: Bundle update fails (eventmachine gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706814/ror-3-1-bundle-update-fails-eventmachine-gem)
I followed the advise to specify the exact version of "eventmachine" in GEMFILE, so I edited it like (hopefully I did it right)

```
gem "sinatra"
gem "mogli"
gem "json"
gem "httparty"
gem "eventmachine"  "1.0.0.beta.4.1"
gem "thin"
```

Now, "bundle install" fails with a different error:

> Could not find gem 'eventmachine1.0.0.beta.4.1 (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

As I mentioned, this version was successfully installed, and it appears in the local repository.

Please help to make "bundle" "happy" with the right 'eventmachine' version.

Sorry if I missed something basic, or failed to find answer already published.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing a comma in this line of the last Gemfile:

```
gem "eventmachine", "1.0.0.beta.4.1"
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed I missed a comma, but yet it did not solve the issue: "bundle install" now complains:You have requested: eventmachine = 1.0.0.beta.4.1 . The bundle currently has eventmachine locked at 0.12.10. Try running `bundle update eventmachine`. Running "update" shows up the original "Could not find gem ... "error message. How to get rid of 0.12.10 ? Thamks

Comment: remove `Gemfile.lock` and re-do a `bundle install`. That should work! Also it would be a great idea to issue `gem clean`